# How do I fetch specific types inheriting from an abstract class from spring-mongodb with one query?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring MongoDb Data, and I have two classes A and B inheriting from class C.
Both A and B has the '_class' field.
I want to fetch a list of documents with both A and B in them, and have them be mapped to their inheriting objects, but using MongoOperation it seems that it's only possible to put one class entity with each query. Is there a way to fetch a list of both A and B and have them polymorphed to their corresponding java objects? Or fetching the abstract C is the only way to fetch both A and B at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single type parameter you hand into the `….find…(…)` methods of `MongoTemplate` is effectively a shortcut to define both the collection to be read and the types of objects to be produced eventually by the document mapping subsystem. It does *not* restrict the document selection in any way. This effectively implements a type-hierarchy-by-collection approach.

If you want to restrict the query result to only some subtypes, you need to use the `Query` type's `….restrict(Class, Class…)` method that allows to define which nominal types are supposed to be read. That effectively translates in to a constraint against the type aliases being persisted on write, as MongoDB documents don't know anything about types on the client in the first place.